# Show the relation $W$ is constant

Tags: physics, classical-mechanics, fluid-dynamics

If the space $W$ is constant (doesn't move with the flow), show that $$\frac{d}{dt}\int_{W}\left (\frac{1}{2}\rho |\overrightarrow{u}|^2+\rho \epsilon\right )dV=-\int_{\partial{W}}\rho \left (\frac{1}{2}|\overrightarrow{u}|^2+i\right )\overrightarrow{u} \cdot \overrightarrow{n}dA$$

where $p$ the pressure, $\rho$ the density, $\epsilon=i-\frac{p}{\rho}$ the internal energy per unit mass, $i$ the enthalpy.

How can we show that?? Do we have to use the divergence theorem??

Comment: Maybe exchange the order of differentiation and integration before using the divergence theorem.

Comment: This is best asked at PHYS.SE

Comment: Ok... Are you familiar with streamlines and pathlines?? @user_of_math

Comment: @MaryStar Yes. Why?

Comment: Could you take a look at my questions: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1310701/streamlines-pathlines and http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/187494/construct-the-streamlines-and-find-the-cutoff-points-of-the-flow ?? @user_of_math