# Streamlines - Pathlines

Tags: physics, classical-mechanics, fluid-dynamics

Construct and draw the streamlines of the velocity field $u=az-bt, v=\frac{b}{4}z-cy, w=2(a-1)$. Calculate $c$ (as a function of the constants $a$, $b$) such that the flow field $\overrightarrow{u}=(u, v, w)$ represents the flow of an incompressible fluid. Find also the pathlines of the element of the fluid that at the time $t=0$ it is at the position $(x_0, y_0, z_0)$.

I have done the following:

$$\frac{dx}{u}=\frac{dy}{v}=\frac{dz}{w}$$

$$\frac{dx}{az-bt}=\frac{dy}{\frac{b}{4}z-cy}=\frac{dz}{2(a-1)}$$

$$\frac{dx}{az-bt}=\frac{dz}{2(a-1)} \Rightarrow 2(a-1)dx=(az-bt)dz \Rightarrow 2(a-1)x=a\frac{z^2}{2}-btz+d$$

$$\frac{dx}{az-bt}=\frac{dy}{\frac{b}{4}z-cy} \Rightarrow \frac{x}{az-bt}=-\frac{\ln \left (\frac{b}{4}z-cy\right )}{c}+m$$

Is this correct so far??

So, which are the streamlines??

From the fact that the fluid is incompressible we have the following:

$$div \overrightarrow{u}=0 \Rightarrow \partial_xu + \partial_yv + \partial_zw=0\\ \Rightarrow -cy=0 \Rightarrow c=0$$

Is this correct??

To find the pathlines we do the following:

- $$\frac{dx(t)}{dt}=u \Rightarrow \frac{dx(t)}{dt}=az-bt \Rightarrow \frac{dx(t)}{dt}=a(2(a-1)+z_0)-bt \\ \Rightarrow \frac{dx(t)}{dt}=2a(a-1)+az_0-bt \Rightarrow x(t)=(2a(a-1)+az_0)t-\frac{b}{2}t^2+x_0 $$
- $$ \frac{dy(t)}{dt}=v \Rightarrow \frac{dy(t)}{dt}=\frac{b}{4}z \Rightarrow \frac{dy(t)}{dt}=\frac{b}{4}(2a(a-1)t+z_0) \\ \Rightarrow \frac{dy(t)}{dt}=\frac{b}{2}a(a-1)t+\frac{bz_0}{4} \Rightarrow y(t)=\frac{b}{4}a(a-1)t^2+\frac{bz_0}{4}t+y_0$$
- $$  \frac{dz(t)}{dt}=w \Rightarrow \frac{dz(t)}{dt}=2(a-1) \Rightarrow z(t)=2(a-1)t+z_0$$

Is this correct??

Comment: Your constant of integration for the streamlines need not be the specified constant "c". Remember you should get a family of curves for your streamlines. There will also be a different coefficient after you integrate to get your log term because of the $b/4$

Comment: I edited it... Is it correct now?? @user_of_math

Comment: computation of  pathlines are wrong. you are assuming $x,y,z$ as functions of time $t$ on the left and then treat them as constant when they are on the right hand side. that cannot be right.

Comment: Oh yes... you are right!! I will compute them again... @abel

Comment: I edited my initial post... Could you tell me if I calculated correct the pathlines?? @abel

Comment: it looks alright; i have not checked all the details though.

Comment: Ok... Are the streamlines that I found correct?? @abel

Comment: i guess you are using $z$ as the parameter to characterize the  streamline curve.

Comment: Is it correct to do so?? @abel

Comment: yes. you can do that.

Comment: So, the streamlines are correct, right?? How can we draw them?? @abel

Comment: what do you mean how you can draw? on a piece of paper? you can only draw the projection of the streamlines and let the imagination do the rest.